# can data from a sensor be read in a function

Tags: sensors, i2c, pic32, mplab-x

I am using the icm 20948 sensor, programming on MPLABx running harmonyV3.i2c is communication mode. Can I read and write in a function, does it have to be in a while loop?

For example would:

```
while(SERCOM1_I2C_IsBusy()) {}
SERCOM1_I2C_Write(ICM20948_ADDRESS,&FAccrangefactor, 1);
```

function properly in a function. Many thanks

Comment: Sure, the main `loop()` function is also nothing but, well, a function. All operations can be performed from everywhere, as long as their sequence is still the same.